# Set timezone in gradle using command line

Tags: gradle

I am trying to run gradle command to set timezone while running a test case 
But I am not able to set the timezone.Whereas the test case works in IDE while adding VM argument as `-Duser.timezone=Europe/London`

Command

```
gradle test --tests abc.MyTest -Duser.timezone=Europe/London
```

Comment: Have you considered refactoring the class under test so that it accepts a timezone (eg in the constructor) rather than referencing `TimeZone.getDefault()`. This way its simple to test different timezones

Comment: i donot want to refractor rather change timezone from command line

Answer (score 1):

Using TZ environment variable

```
TZ=GMT ./gradlew clean test
```